How to configure connection to database with impersonate_user = True?
I trying make access to dashboard to every employee of company.
For every employee I create user with role "salary_role". 
Next I add this role in dashboard roles.




dashboard_title
role_name




0
my_dashboard
salary_role


1
my_dashboard
Admin



And give all permissions for this role, including all dataset used in dashboard or filters.
I can open "my_dashboard" with this user "user_test" (role "salary_role"), but I see errors:
Cannot load filter
Error: HTTPDriver for http://clickhouse:8123 received ClickHouse error code 516 Code: 516. DB::Exception: user_test: Authentication failed: password is incorrect, or there is no user with such name. (AUTHENTICATION_FAILED) (version 24.1.5.6 (official build)) 

I got Superset, version 4.0.2 (I've updated version) with Docker.
Connection to database settings:



created_on
changed_on
id
database_name
sqlalchemy_uri
created_by_fk
changed_by_fk
password
cache_timeout
extra
select_as_create_table_as
allow_ctas
expose_in_sqllab
force_ctas_schema
allow_run_async
allow_dml
verbose_name
impersonate_user
allow_file_upload
encrypted_extra
server_cert
allow_cvas
uuid
configuration_method
is_managed_externally
external_url




2024-05-15 18:34:26.633130
2024-05-15 18:34:26.633137
2
Clickhouse Connect
clickhousedb://root:XXXXXXXXXX@clickhouse
1
1
<memory at 0x0000014D6E704A00>
0
{}
False
True
True

True
True

True
True
<memory at 0x0000014D6E704D00>

True
c5e76bea-53d6-4fa7-a7db-200ec07069b7
sqlalchemy_form
True




In this table I found setting "impersonate_user = True".
It means that for every Superset user will be used original login and password.
So my final question: how configure Superset to work with impersonate_user setting?
Thanks!

You always connect to Superset with a user, the role doesn't matter.  What do you mean by set "root" user?

I found that this error caused by impersonate_user setting for connection. So I updated my question.

not sure, but looks like superset users is not the same with clickhouse users, so if impersonate_user is superset settings, then this is have no effect to clickhouse server connection properties

I've tryed create 2 same account for Superset and Clickhouse, but it's not helping. I think, there's need to correct Superset / Clickhouse config, but I can't find information I need, =/
